# why document.getElementById return null when get multi iframe in page

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

i try this page, only if1 return , if2 and if3 return null, why?below is the html codes thanks. ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rGq9R/))

```
     <html>
 <head>
  <title> New Document </title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  <!--
    function dotest() {
        alert(document.getElementById("if1"));
        alert(document.getElementById("if2"));
        alert(document.getElementById("if3"));
    }
  //-->
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
 <input type="button" value="Test Test" onclick="dotest()">
  <iframe id="if1"/>
  <iframe id="if2"/>
  <iframe id="if3"/>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't self-close iframe tags. Change them to this:

```
<iframe id="if1"></iframe>
<iframe id="if2"></iframe>
<iframe id="if3"></iframe>
```

What happens is that the browser thinks the first iframe isn't closed so it implicitly closes it at the end of the document, and anything inside the tag is considered a fallback for browsers that don't support iframes.

Answer (score 1):

Try to actually close the iframe tags:

```
<iframe id="if1"></iframe>
<iframe id="if2"></iframe>
<iframe id="if3"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

iframe is not self closing tag

```
<iframe id="if1"></iframe>
<iframe id="if2"></iframe>
<iframe id="if3"></iframe>
```

[see here](http://www.littlewebhut.com/articles/html_iframe_example/)

Comment: I didn't downvote, but at the time you received the downvote the answer was just "Try `<iframe id="if1"></iframe>`" which someone might see as too thin for an answer.